# Vim use alt+j / alt+k to move lines down/up in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vim

I just started using Linux, I've been using Mac for a while and I'm trying to setup my .vimrc so I can move lines up/down with alt+k/alt+j as I do on my Mac

This is what I have in my .vimrc on my Mac:

```
noremap wq :wq<CR>"
nnoremap ∆ :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap ˚ :m .-2<CR>==

inoremap ∆ <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap ˚ <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

vnoremap ∆ :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap ˚ :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

that works perfectly for Mac so I was searching for options for Linux and I've tried all of the followings without success

```
nnoremap ^[k <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap ^[j <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

nnoremap [k <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap [j <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

nnoremap <A-K> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap <A-J> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

nnoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

nnoremap <M-k> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap <M-j> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi

nnoremap <M-K> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap <M-J> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
```

It might be worth mentioning that I'm using Gnome Tweaks to remap my super key to alt.

However when I go in vim, go in insert mode and hit CTRL+v and the press alt+j (super+j on my keyboard), I'm indeed seeing `^[j` so I'm thinking that this should be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting this in your vimrc

```
set <A-k>=^[k
set <A-j>=^[j
" and so on
```

(as you know already, `^[k` is obtained via <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Alt+k</kbd>) and using your fourth alternative mappings?

```
nnoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
nnoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
```